# How to replicate a list a certain number of times

Tags: python, list

I want to replicate a list more than 1000 times and then append to a larger list.

For instance:

```
a = ['1','2','3','4]
```

When replicating this list and then nesting it a hundred times:

```
output = [['1','2','3','4],['1','2','3','4],['1','2','3','4],['1','2','3','4],['1','2','3','4].....]
```

So far I've only come across a*2, which is not want I want.

Comment: Try [a]*5.......

Comment: Do you want the sublists to be independent, or do you want them all to be references to the one `a` list? IOW, if you do `output[1][1] = '5'`, do you want `output` to become `[['1', '5', '3', '4'], ['1', '5', '3', '4'], ['1', '5', '3', '4'], ...]` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can easily replicate the list by the following.

```
a = ['1','2','3','4']
output = [a]*1000
```

The above will create reference.
If you need separate copy then do the following.

```
a = ['1','2','3','4']
output = [a[:] for i in range(1000)]
```

Answer (score 5):

In that case you should use `[a]*2`. But note that the `*` operator will create multiply references to your main object, since it's a mutable object. Instead as a more pythonic way you can use `itertools.repeat()` which will give you separate copies of your main object:

```
In [2]: from itertools import repeat

In [5]: a = ['1','2','3','4']

In [6]: list(repeat(a, 4))
Out[6]: 
[['1', '2', '3', '4'],
 ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
 ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
 ['1', '2', '3', '4']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. While `a * 2` may give you `[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, there is a way to use that same operator to get the result you want. It's just repeating the contents, so try `[a] * 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension

```
>>> b = [a for i in range(3)]
>>> b
[['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['1', '2', '3', '4']]
```

You can do various such operations over lists.
Check this link [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you need to replicate list without using same reference to perform some operation in future.

you will try this piece of code to generate a list containing n times replicated list

```
import copy
a = [1,2,3,4]
n = 1000
def replicateMaster(n, a):
    output= []
    while n != 0:
        n -= 1
        output.append(copy.deepcopy(a))
    return output
```

Or simply use this shorthand:

```
import copy
a = [1,2,3,4]
n = 1000
output = [copy.deepcopy(a) for i in range(n)]
```

hopefully this code is solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

try

```
output = print([a]*no_of_count)
```